# word count redirect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, files, wc

[image]

I can't seem to answer this question:

> Use the command `wc` to count the number of words in the file `/course/linuxgym/gutenberg/0ws0310.txt`. Store the exact output of the wc command when used with the "word counts" option into the file `count.txt`. Ensure that the filename within the file contains the full pathname.

Comment: What have you tried?  What result did you get?  Please edit your question and add those details.

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and then learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This'll make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Where is this question from? Are you taking a class, or online assessment?

Comment: Please post text as text. Pictures of text are hard to read. Especially my blind people.

Comment: First no need to touch that file. 2nd look at your 3rd line. What is it that you are re-directing?

Comment: Are you following along with http://linuxgym.it.uts.edu.au/linuxgym/lgwww/ ?

Answer (score 1):

The question in your assignment asks you to use the "word count option" of `wc`.  To find out what option this is, you need to read the `wc` manual.  You do this with `man wc` in a terminal.

Once you have found what option is needed to only get the word count (and no other count), you need to run the command on the file `/course/linuxgym/gutenberg/0ws0310.txt` while at the same time redirecting the output to a file called `count.txt`.  You do this with

```
wc (insert word count option here) /course/linuxgym/gutenberg/0ws0310.txt >count.txt
```

If you want to make sure that the output file is located in your home directory, use `~/count.txt` in the redirection in place of `count.txt`, or just give the command `cd` first to make your home directory your current directory.

There is no need to `touch` the `count.txt` file first as redirecting to it will create it if it does not already exist.